# mariadb installing on ubuntu mate cluster

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, cluster-computing, kaa, galera

I'm trying to install mariadb on a cluster (ubuntu mate 16.04) with 3 nodes.
I did all the things that [this link](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Cluster-setup/MariaDB-cluster-setup-guide/) said, but after running :

```
sudo service mysql start —wsrep-new-cluster
```

I get this error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
```

I checked status, but I couldn't understand the problem:

```
mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since سه<U+200C>شنبه 2018-02-06 
11:36:14 IRST; 5min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 16232 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)

فوریه 06 11:36:16 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:16 [ERROR] 
WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1404: Fail
فوریه 06 11:36:16 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:16 [ERROR] 
WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed 
فوریه 06 11:36:16 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:16 [ERROR] 
WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://11.0.0.1,11.0.
فوریه 06 11:36:16 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:16 [ERROR] 
Aborting
فوریه 06 11:36:16 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 
فوریه 06 11:36:16 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:16 [Note] 
WSREP: Service disconnected.
فوریه 06 11:36:17 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:17 [Note] 
WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
فوریه 06 11:36:17 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 180206 11:36:17 [Note] 
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
فوریه 06 11:36:17 compute-00 mysqld[17101]: 
فوریه 06 11:36:17 compute-00 mysqld_safe[17477]: mysqld from pid file 
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

any help would be appreciated.

P.S. the nodes are:

compute-00 11.0.0.1 (master)

compute-01 11.0.0.2

compute-02 11.0.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way of installing maria galera:
[installing mariadb galera on ubuntu 16.04 cluster with 3 nodes](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-galera-cluster-on-ubuntu-1604/)